# Upgrading a feature in Sharepoint Online

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online

I have a sandbox solution running in Sharepoint Online. Now I've made some changes, like addind fields to content types and changing the contents of some module files.

I know that in order to upgrade the solution, I need to run `Update-SPUserSolution` in Powershell, or call `SPFeature.Upgrade()` in code. However, the former is out of question due to it being Sharepoint Online, and the latter is not available in sandbox solutions.

I have tried adding a version number and adding some tags to the feature manifest. The code goes like this:

```
<UpgradeActions>
  <VersionRange BeginVersion="0.0.0.0" EndVersion="0.9.9.9">
    <AddContentTypeField ContentTypeId="foo" FieldId="blablabla..." PushDown="TRUE"/>
  </VersionRange>
</UpgradeActions>
```

(The previous feature definition had no version number, the current one is 1.0.0.0).

Then I packaged it, uploaded the WSP, then used upgrade functionality available in the solution gallery. It did activate the new solution while at the same time deactivating the old one. However, nothing changed with the content type in question.

Help?